# PhoneGap Android copy to clipboard plugin implementation

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to use [this plugin](https://github.com/jacob/ClipboardManagerPlugin/tree/master/v2.0.0) in my application.  I've never written a plugin and this is my first time trying to use one in my Phonegap program.  I had to try and change a whole bunch of stuff in the java file to get rid of the errors.  When I click a button on my screen, I get an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/js/clipboardmanager.js:2".  No idea what that means or how to change that.  I'll try and paste everything so hopefully it's easier to find my error.

structure:

```
src
-->com.example.basket
  -->MainActivity.java
-->com.saaticiouglu.phonegap.ClipboardManagerPlugin
  -->ClipboardManagerPlugin.java
```

ClipboardManagerPlugin.java:

```
package com.saatcioglu.phonegap.ClipboardManagerPlugin;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;


import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class ClipboardManagerPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {
private static final String actionCopy = "copy";
private static final String actionPaste = "paste";
private static final String errorParse = "Couldn't get the text to copy";
private static final String errorUnknown = "Unknown Error";

private ClipboardManager mClipboardManager;


@SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
  public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext)
  {

    // If we do not have the clipboard
    if(mClipboardManager == null) {
        mClipboardManager = (ClipboardManager) cordova.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    }


    // Copy
    if (action.equals(actionCopy)) {
        String arg = "";
        try {
            arg = (String) args.get(0);
            mClipboardManager.setText(arg);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
              callbackContext.error( errorParse);
        } catch (Exception e) {
              callbackContext.error( errorUnknown);
        }
        callbackContext.success();
    // Paste
    } else if (action.equals(actionPaste)) {
        String arg = (String) mClipboardManager.getText();
        if (arg == null) {
            arg = "";
        }
        PluginResult copy_ret = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, arg);
        callbackContext.sendPluginResult(copy_ret);
        callbackContext.success();

    } else {
          callbackContext.error("invalid action");
          return false;
    }

    return true;
 }
}
```

I had to use the Surpress warnings because setText and getText were giving me errors...and they are still crossed out in my file.  But no errors there now...

clipboardmanager.js:

```
window.clipboardManagerCopy = function(str, success, fail) {
cordova.exec(success, fail, "ClipboardManagerPlugin", "copy", [str]);
};

window.clipboardManagerPaste = function(success, fail) {
cordova.exec(success, fail, "ClipboardManagerPlugin", "copy", []);
};
```

I referenced to the JS file in my index.html:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
            window.clipboardManagerCopy(
                "the text to copy",
                function(r){alert("copy is successful")},
                function(e){alert(e)}
            );
        });
```

I just want to get a simple alert to see that it works.  Thanks for taking the time to help out.  Please help me fix this!!!

Comment: Sounds like Cordova isn't being loaded. Do you link the jquery and then cordova files? Maybe Cordova.js needs to come first in your HTML. Also, does the plain "Hello Cordova" work (eg, does it show Device Ready?)

Comment: Wow...I feel dumb.  I forgot to reference the cordova.js file.  WOW!!!!  Staring at the screen all day and such a dumb mistake!  Thanks!